# How to keep relative sized child elements within the border of the parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have a kind of "range display", where I use elements to display the current position within a range. See the example https://jsfiddle.net/juwxdb5m/ or the following code.

HTML:

```
<h1>Range display with fixed sizes (works correctly)</h1>
<div class="my-fixed-frame">
  <div class="my-fixed-chart">
    <div class="my-fixed-point" style="bottom:0%;left:0%;"></div>
    <div class="my-fixed-point" style="bottom:50%;left:50%;"></div>
    <div class="my-fixed-point" style="bottom:100%;left:100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Range display with relative sizes (works incorrectly)</h1>
<div class="my-relative-frame">
  <div class="my-relative-chart">
    <div class="my-relative-point" style="bottom:0%;left:0%;"></div>
    <div class="my-relative-point" style="bottom:50%;left:50%;"></div>
    <div class="my-relative-point" style="bottom:100%;left:100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-fixed-frame {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
}

.my-fixed-chart {
  background-color: silver;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 8px; left: 8px; right: 8px; top: 8px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.my-fixed-point {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 16px;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
}

.my-relative-frame {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
}

.my-relative-chart {
  background-color: silver;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 25%; left: 25%; right: 25%; top: 25%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.my-relative-point {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -25%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}
```

When I use fixed sizes, I can implement the design as desired. The "point" elements are within the parent element, respectively within its frame.

But I didn't found a solution, when I use relative sizes for the child elements.

Comment: Well for one thing, you are using extremely large and inequivalent sizes for your relative stuff. 25% is not nearly the same as 8px. Is this what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/pzqsbwco/1/ Also, what exactly do you want to be "relative"? The green boxes? The chart? or the frame?

Comment: Yes, the green boxes. If I have i.e. four possible positions on x-axis, I would like to have a width of 25% for the green boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works as desired, see also https://jsfiddle.net/juwxdb5m/1/.

HTML:

```
<h1>Range display with relative sizes</h1>
<div class="range-display">
  <div class="range-cocoon">
    <div class="range-point" style="bottom:0%;left:0%;"></div>
    <div class="range-point" style="bottom:33.333%;left:33.333%;"></div>
    <div class="range-point" style="bottom:66.666%;left:66.666%;"></div>
    <div class="range-point" style="bottom:100%;left:100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.range-display {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
}

.range-cocoon {
  background-color: silver;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 75%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
}

.range-point {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 33.333%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/xoq95xaa/

The main changes are that I took the green squares out of the inner container (which is what you kind of did using negative margins in the first version), removed any margins, inserted a forth element (reacting to your comment), changed the size to 25% width and height and changed the `bottom` and `left` values to 25% steps (0, 25, 50, 75).

Comment: This is a good answer but unfortunatelly not exactly what I want. It is possible to set `bottom` and `left` from 0 to 100? Like in a slider component?

Comment: Is this maybe better? https://jsfiddle.net/0j18dnnf/ If you want values like left:50% to position at exactly 50% of the container, translating is great trick to accomplish that

Comment: yes, any JS/jQuery script should be able to set bottom and left dynamically to any value. But 100/100 will already be outside of the container, so the range should be between 0 and 75 (which you can calculate/convert to percentages by using `positionvalue = percentagevalue * 0.75 ` on the values in the script.

Comment: @JdFrancis: Translating of the element is a good hint. I have to test around with it.